# I am limited to the number of requests that the map provider can provide me using OpenLayer?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I will build a webApp for my computing course but I want to build a app that I'm not limited to the number of requests, mapLoads of the free tier of the API. Can the tools who comes with the OpenLayer overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OpenLayers, you can choose among hosted map services like OpenStreetMap, Bing or Here. Or you can use your own maps, e.g. tiles you host yourself, or a WMS service.

Of the available hosted map services, [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org/) is probably the most liberal one when it comes to the number of requests. Make sure you always review the terms of use of the map services you are using. For OpenStreetMap, you can find the usage policy here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy.